# Is my thread in the Ready Queue?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, winapi

I need to log when and for how long a specific thread is in the Ready Queue.
I wonder if there is a programmatic way to do that with C#.
Tell me if you need more information...

Thanks in advance,
Rotem Varon.

Comment: Do you want to know in which state is the thread in the kernel? Since you are mentioning the "ready queue"..

Comment: Clarification:
The end game here is to check how long some set of threads (which I have no control of, I am not writing the code for those threads) are waiting for CPU resource.
Is there a way to get a snapshot of the current ready queue?

Comment: Added answer below with details

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `ThreadState` property of the `Thread` object.

See the possibile values here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx

`WaitSleepJoin` indicates it's waiting for something, `Running` means it's in the 'ready queue' as far as I know.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, running means that it is either in the ready queue or currently executing... or in the deferred ready or standy queues 
http://www.adamcarnahan.com/windows/NtExecution.jpg

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
One important piece of information I forgot to mention is that I am not writing the code for the thread. I am merely an observer.
I guess the subject should be change to “given a thread, how can I know if this thread is in Ready state?” or something...
Thanks,
Rotem

Answer (score 0):

The information about the kernel state of a thread is available in the [KTHREAD kernel structure](http://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/KTHREAD.html), accessible through the thread block in kernel mode.

The question is how to surface it or expose it to a program in user mode? Probably the best solution given time and skills is to write a kernel driver.

Alternatively you may look to the windows performance counters, which may already do it for you. In any case, you have to resort to rather imprecise polling (you do not get a notification WHEN the thread change state).

The [Win32_Thread WMI  class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394494%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) may be useful for you, especially the `ExecutionState` field.